# How can I reuse the model or DAL & BLL with MVC web pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on this demo project, which has following requirement.

`Requirement:` One Survey app, which has questions and objective type answers (option a, option b... Option n). Among which, user need to give one or more answer and also s/he may submit a better answer as well.

(As this project has one survey module which I need to develop in the MVC framework & rest of the project is in the ASP.NET.

`Confusion 1:` I am confused over, how could I reuse the existing model & old `SDA` style connectivity to perform binding with the new app. As per MVC- more html focused on asp.net platform approach excludes binding control & all other. (Otherwise I would work it as Independent module, New model-view-controller connectivity.

`Confuion 2:` Could this survey app deploy as just another module of this app over the server or Independent one.

**UPDATE**: *My question is in regard to reusing MODEL of old .ASPX project in MVC project*

Comment: The first thing that come to my mind is to make some common library and then reuse it in both mvc and webforms project.

Comment: @rosko : thanks for your quick response. As the asp.net part has done by other offshore team- has contain two full flag `dal` & `bll`. Which are a bit cumbersome task to understand and move around, to me. If you could elaborate on this issue as well, it will a great help to me. Thank you so much..!

Comment: If their architecture is really bad written then reusing it in other project may be really difficult and time consuming... It even may require a total rewritting in the worst scenario. At this point I think that I can't really help you and suggest something better. There is one thing to remember: think about the architecture and structure of your application before actually coding it. This would save the time that you are now wasting to solve this implementation problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use ASP.NET MVC together with regular ASP.NET Web forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541703/can-i-use-asp-net-mvc-together-with-regular-asp-net-web-forms)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541703/can-i-use-asp-net-mvc-together-with-regular-asp-net-web-forms

Comment: @chiccodoro @Simranjeet, thanks for response. Regarding my question, I was doubtful over "how could I reuse `MODEL`, i.e. `DAL` & `BLL`.."

I have just read the given thread- the possible duplicate & I am glad to know, that we can mix web-forms in the regular MVC project. But it doesn't solve my query in anyway. Thanks again both of you!!

Comment: @Prabhat - sorry, retracted my close vote

Comment: @chiccodoro : I should say thanks to you, 'cuz in this way I got a chance to put the accurate heading to this question. However, sorry for taking your valuable time. Thanks again..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading all of this again I realize that by your `DAL` and `BLL` abbreviations which in a quick first glance looked like some technology alien to me, you actually simply meant to say **data access layer** and **business logic layer**.

Now this really boils the question down to:

1. How can I reuse code in two projects (one webforms project and one mvc project), and
2. Do I have to use two projects at all or can I pack all in one?

I feel that both of these questions should be answered by now:

**As for 1.:** Do as rosko suggested - put your DAL and BLL in a library project and use from both your MVC and your Webforms project.

**As for 2.:** No you don't have to, MVC and webforms can co-exist. That's what the "possible duplicate" link as well as chandresh's answer is about.

---

I take it that your actual question is more between the lines: The question of whether you can use the current DAL *technology* and the data-binding mechanism in an MVC project.

Now MVC is just a web framework. Although many MVC projects use Entity Framework, there is nothing stopping you from reusing any DAL technology you like. You can render your razor views from a data source if you really want to do agonize.

However if you're used to [binding web controls to a data source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984209%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), that will be different in MVC. Two-way binding is not really possible if the "control" lives in a web browser on the user's computer while the data source is on a web server. WebForms just mimics this using its page viewstate, postback and event handling cycle.

In MVC rendering a page from given data (*View*) and receiving updated data from a user (*Controller*) are done in completely different places. Two-way bindings in modern web application usually happen in the browser, using javascript libraries such as [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/), combined with ajax-based libraries to synchronize the local changes with the server, such as [Breeze](http://www.breezejs.com/).

Searching for "databinding", "mvc", and/or "datasource" I also found these related questions:

- [ASP.Net MVC framework and databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281144/asp-net-mvc-framework-and-databinding),
- [how I can bind my datasource to view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729107/how-i-can-bind-my-datasource-to-view), or
- [ASP.NET MVC Two Way Data Binding of Model to Radio Button List using Typed Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874845/asp-net-mvc-two-way-data-binding-of-model-to-radio-button-list-using-typed-model).

Now I really invested a whole lot of time, so I expect an upvote and an accept from you :-)</kidding>

Comment: @chiccodoro- you are the *guru* boss... Actually, you have caught the real confusion of my mind & have opened all the windows of my brain and certainly taught(slapped) me about how to use search engines effectively. :) I am really glad to have such excellent answer and possible clue to make use of `DAL` & `BLL`. Thanks so much for giving me a ray of hope to move in the right direction. Thanks a lot..!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, you can work on both simultaneously in single project. If you create a mvc project 
and add aspx webforms init they will run. In best scenerio you don't need to do any extra work.

[Can I use ASP.NET MVC together with regular ASP.NET Web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541703/can-i-use-asp-net-mvc-together-with-regular-asp-net-web-forms)

Comment: Links given there are useful to differentiate between both (.aspx & mvc) thanks!